# I am stuck on the gitlab ci cd pipeline code because I can't get the Merge_Request creator name in a predefined variable

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, gitlab-api

I am stuck on the gitlab ci/cd pipeline code because I can't get the Merge_Request creator name in a predefined variable.

Please help me for getting Merge_Request creator / author name in gitlab ci/cd

I need some Merge_Request author name in gitlab ci/cd pipeline

Comment: MR author is not a pre-defined variable. What are you stuck on? Can you provide at least an excerpt of your CI YAML file and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You can get merge request author by using API and predefined variables. Check this endpoint `/projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid`  (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#get-single-mr). Instead of attributes `id` and `merge_request_iid` you should use variables `CI_PROJECT_ID` and `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID`. Then you can filter response by jq tool.

Something like this:

```bash
curl -X GET -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${ACESS_TOKEN}" ${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/merge_requests/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID} | jq .author.username
```